# como obtener el ultimo del array y hacer find

Tags: javascript

Hola Productos es un objeto   que lo inserto en el array
luego trato de encontrar el ultimo elemento insertado en dicho array
y sobre el hacer la busqueda con find

pero no me resulta porque ese elemento debo preguntar si su id es igual al parametro que viene de la funcion

```
function addToCarritoItem(e,id){
 
  let itemProductos = Productos;
  arreglo.push(itemProductos)



  let itemProducto =arreglo[arreglo.length - 1].find(({id_a}) => id_a === id);
  console.log(arreglo)
  }
```

Comment: El código de la pregunta luce incompleto. Probablemente haría falta ver la definición o contenido de `Productos` y de `arreglo`, así como saber cuál es el resultado esperado de la función o qué es lo que no está funcionando en ella. Por favor lee [mcve]. Cuándo publicas código en una pregunta es importante que el ejemplo sea **completo** (que es lo que le falta a este) y mínimo, que es que tenga solo el código relevante al problema en torno al que gira la pregunta y nada más que eso.